# How to make a custom hook for tooltip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have made a navbar component and I am using JSX and in this component I want to use tooltip, but when I want to use tooltip I have to manually code the each tooltip with title prop.

For example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

export default function BasicTooltip() {
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Delete">
      <IconButton>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

This is the official code from Material-UI (MUI) site ignore icon button and icon I have my own icons.

```
import { Button, styled } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import {
  AccountCircleIcon,
  WorkIcon,
  LocalActivityIcon,
  PersonIcon,
  CategoryIcon,
  AssessmentIcon,
  Company,
  LogoutIcon,
} from "../assets/icons";
import "../styles/Navbar.css";
import useAlert from "../hooks/useAlert";

const Navbar = () => {
  const { notify, Toaster } = useAlert();

  const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
    backgroundColor: "#D6E4EC",
    color: "#2F4F4F",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#abc4ff",
      color: "#2b2d42",
    },
  });

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <img src={Company} className="company-logo " alt="company-logo" />
      <Toaster />
      <ul>
        <li className="nav-item">
          
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            size="small"
            startIcon={<AccountCircleIcon />}
            onClick={() => notify("Account")}
          >
            Account
          </CustomButton>
          
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<WorkIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            Opportunities
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<LocalActivityIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            Activities
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<PersonIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            People
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<CategoryIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            Products
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<AssessmentIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            Reports
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <CustomButton
            className="Button"
            startIcon={<LogoutIcon />}
            size="small"
          >
            Logout
          </CustomButton>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I have tried making a custom hook but it is not working the way I wanted.

Comment: What exactly is the issue or problem you have with your code? Please [edit] to clarify, anything more than "it's not working", and include a complete [mcve] if there is any other relevant code you haven't shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your CustomButton component with MUI Tooltip component.

You don't have to manually code each tooltip with title prop. Simply create an array of objects with the required props and use map to iteratively render your button.

```
const buttonProps = [
    {
        id: 0,
        buttonName: "Account",
        icon: <AccountCircleIcon />
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        buttonName: "Opportunities",
        icon: <WorkIcon />
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        buttonName: "Activities",
        icon: <LocalActivityIcon />
    },
]


return (
    <div className="navbar">
    <img src={Company} className="company-logo " alt="company-logo" />
    <Toaster />
  
    <ul>
        {buttonProps.map(button => 
    
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Tooltip title={button.buttonName}>
              <CustomButton
                className="Button"
                size="small"
                startIcon={button.icon}
                onClick={() => notify(`${button.buttonName}`)}
              >
                {button.name}
              </CustomButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </li>
    
      )}
  </ul>
  </div>
);
```